# Xamarin: FFImageLoading not showing using inside list view on iOS

Tags: ios, image, xamarin, image-loading, ffimageloading

I am currently using FFImageLoading library on a listView inside the custom data template.

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Clicked="OnDelete" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" Text="Delete" IsDestructive="True" />
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                            <StackLayout
                                Padding="12,10,12,10" 
                                BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                                Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image
                                    DownsampleToViewSize="true"
                                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                                    Source="{Binding FileThumbnail, Converter={StaticResource mimeTypeToImageConverter}}"
                                    WidthRequest="60"
                                    HeightRequest="60">
                                </Image>
```

Inside the mimeTypeToImageConverter:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string)
        {
            var file = (string)value;     

            if (FileUtilities.IsImageType(file))
            {
                //var fileImageSource = new FileImageSource();
                //fileImageSource.File = file;
                var imageSource = ImageSource.FromFile(file);
                return imageSource;
            } 
            else {
                return ImageSource.FromFile("ic_file_white.png");
            }

        } 
        return null;
    }
```

I used on android but android works fine. When I change back to Image control, the iOS will show the image.

I really need it to reduce the image size. Does any of you got that problem before.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the Image Control, you need to use the FFImageLoading Control

Change

```
<Image>...</Image>
```

to

```
<forms:CachedImage>...</forms:CachedImage>
```

Also add the namespace

```
<ContentPage xmlns:forms="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms">
```

CachedImage should have all of the same properties as Image

Oops forgot to mention, you will need to add DownsampleHeight or DownsampleWidth to reduce the size as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are trying do download images by http, not https?

You need to add folowing to your info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: no i use the photo from photo library in the phone.